# Why is binary_crossentropy more accurate than categorical_crossentropy for multiclass classification in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm learning how to create convolutional neural networks using Keras. I'm trying to get a high accuracy for the MNIST dataset.

Apparently `categorical_crossentropy` is for more than 2 classes and `binary_crossentropy` is for 2 classes. Since there are 10 digits, I should be using `categorical_crossentropy`. However, after training and testing dozens of models, `binary_crossentropy` consistently outperforms `categorical_crossentropy` significantly.

On Kaggle, I got 99+% accuracy using `binary_crossentropy` and 10 epochs. Meanwhile, I can't get above 97% using `categorical_crossentropy`, even using 30 epochs (which isn't much, but I don't have a GPU, so training takes forever).

Here's what my model looks like now:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(100, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(28, 28, 1), init='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(100, 3, 3, init='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, init='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(100, init='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(10, init='glorot_uniform', activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer: it is **not**.

To see that, simply try to calculate the accuracy "by hand", and you will see that it is different from the one reported by Keras with the `model.evaluate` method:

```python
# Keras reported accuracy:
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0) 
score[1]
# 0.99794011611938471

# Actual accuracy calculated manually:
import numpy as np
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
acc = sum([np.argmax(y_test[i])==np.argmax(y_pred[i]) for i in range(10000)])/10000
acc
# 0.98999999999999999
```

The reason it *seems* to be so is a rather subtle issue at how Keras actually *guesses* which accuracy to use, depending on the loss function you have selected, when you include simply `metrics=['accuracy']` in your model compilation.

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py), Keras does not define a single accuracy metric, but several different ones, among them `binary_accuracy` and `categorical_accuracy`. What happens [under the hood](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L876) is that, since you have selected binary cross entropy as your loss function and have not specified a particular accuracy metric, Keras (wrongly...) infers that you are interested in the `binary_accuracy`, and this is what it returns.

To avoid that, i.e. to use indeed binary cross entropy as your loss function (nothing wrong with this, in principle) while still getting the **categorical** accuracy required by the problem at hand (i.e. MNIST classification), you should ask explicitly for `categorical_accuracy` in the model compilation as follows:

```python
from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax', metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
```

And after training, scoring, and predicting the test set as I show above, the two metrics now are the same, as they should be:

```python
sum([np.argmax(y_test[i])==np.argmax(y_pred[i]) for i in range(10000)])/10000 == score[1]
# True
```

(HT to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/keras-binary-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-performance/44498955#44498955) to a similar problem, which helped me understand the issue...)

**UPDATE**: After my post, I discovered that this issue had already been identified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799474/keras-model-evaluate-vs-model-predict-accuracy-difference-in-multi-class-nlp-ta/45834857#45834857).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, binary_crossentropy is not when there are two classes.

The "binary" name is because it is adapted for binary output, and each number of the softmax is aimed at being 0 or 1.
Here, it checks for each number of the output.

It doesn't explain your result, since categorical_entropy exploits the fact that it is a classification problem.

Are you sure that when you read your data there is one and only one class per sample? It's the only one explanation I can give.