# Keras - model.predict_classes gives wrong labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

My model is like

```python
print('Build main model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([left, right], mode='sum'))
model.add(Dense(14, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

when I use `model.evaluate([xtest1, xtest2], y_test)`, I get an accuracy of 90% but when I use `model.predict_classes([x_test1, x_xtest2])`, I get totally wrong class labels, going by which my accuracy drops significantly. What is the difference in `model.evaluate` and `model.predict_classes` schema? Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: can you provide your complete code along with how you are calculating accuracy in a better-formatted way

Comment: How many classes do you have? I guess they are more than 2...

Comment: @desertnaut, yes there are 14 classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you ask for `loss='binary_cross_entropy'` and `metric=['accuracy']` in your model compilation, Keras infers that you are interested in the *binary* accuracy, and this is what it returns in `model.evaluate()`; in fact, since you have 14 classes, you are actually interested in the *categorical* accuracy, which is the one reported via `model.predict_classes()`.

So, you should change the loss function in your model compilation to `categorical_crossentropy`:

```python
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If, for whatever reason, you want to stick with `loss='binary_crossentropy'` (admittedly it would be a very unusual choice) , you should change the model compilation to clarify that you want the categorical accuracy as follows:

```python
from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
```

In either of these cases, you will find that the accuracies reported by `model.evaluate()` and `model.predict_classes()` are the  same, as they should be.

For a more detailed explanation and an example using the MNIST data, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/keras-binary-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-performance/46038271#46038271).