# Keras merging class prediction with labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When training my network, I have a multi label classification problem in which I convert the class labels into one hot encoding.

After training the model, and generating predictions - keras simply outputs an array of values without specifying the class label.

What is best practice to merge these, so my API can return meaningful results to the consumer?

Example

```
y = pd.get_dummies(df_merged.eventId)
y

2CBC9h3uple1SXxEVy8W    GiiFxmfrUwBNMGgFuoHo    e06onPbpyCucAGXw01mM
12  1                   0                       0
13  1                   0                       0
14  1                   0                       0

prediction = model.predict(pred_test_input)
prediction
array([[0.5002058 , 0.49697363, 0.50251794]], dtype=float32)
```

Desired outcome:
`{results: { 2CBC9h3uple1SXxEVy8W: 0.5002058, ...}`

EDIT: Adding model as per comment - but this is just a toy model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(
  Embedding(
    input_dim=embeddings_index.shape[0],
    output_dim=embeddings_index.shape[1],
    weights=[embeddings_index],
    input_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
    trainable=False,
  )
)
model.add(LSTM(300))
model.add(Dense(units=len(y.columns), activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

EDIT 2 - adding y.

So my `y` is in the following format:

```
eventId
123
123
234
...
```

I then use `y = pd.get_dummies(df_merged.eventId)` to convert this into something the model can consume and would like to append the eventIds back to the predictions.

Comment: This depends on the model structure, please include it, specially the output layers

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro added - but this is just a placeholder really.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are doing multi-label classification, then you should use the `binary_crossentropy` loss:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then it is important to say that keras' accuracy does not consider multi-label classification, so it will be a misleading metric. More appropriate metrics are precision/recall for each class.

To get class predictions, you have to threshold each class' predictions, and it is a threshold that you have to tune (it does not have to be the same for each class), so for example:

```
class_names = y.columns.tolist()
pred_classes = {}
preds = model.predict(pred_test_input)

thresh = 0.5
for i in range(num_classes):
    if preds[i] > thresh:
        pred_classes[class_name[i]] = preds[i]
```

This will output the `pred_classes` dictionary with the classes over the threshold, and include a confidence score.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, however where does `class_name` come from the `preds` list does not have any reference to the labels.

Comment: @dendog That is external to Keras, its just a mapping from class index to class name, its the inverse operation from when you encoded your labels into a numeric form.

Comment: This is exactly the part I wanted help with - to ensure they are mapped correctly. Do you have an example of a helper function here to create that mapping? I am going to add my code which creates dummies.

Comment: Also @Matias Valdenegro please check your comment regarding binary cross entropy most of the resources I see state it is for two classes only.

Comment: @dendog There is nothing to check, you are doing multi-label classification, which is N binary classification problems, where N is the number of classes.

Comment: @dendog So you can use class_names = y.columns.tolist(), it should give you the array mapping.

Comment: take a look at this - sorry to keep harping on but just trying to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/keras-binary-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-performance

Comment: @dendog What should I look there? It is a bit rude to just throw links to people.

Comment: Sorry @Matias Valdenegro - was not trying to be rude, it was in relation to the binary vs categorical loss discussion

Comment: @dendog You told us that you are doing multi-label classification, see this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175655/349130

Comment: Ok thanks! Seems you are correct - I did not expect the distinction between class/label