# Evaluating a Multi-Label Classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, multilabel-classification

I currently have a multi-label classification problem, for which I am using keras to build a neural network as follows:

```
n_cols = dataset.shape[1]
print(n_cols)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(26, activation='sigmoid')) # Sigmoid for multi-label classification

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.5, nesterov=True)
#RMSprop
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

## Fit the model ##
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=20)
history = model.fit(dataset, labels, validation_split=0.33, epochs=30, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I was informed that for multi-label classification, we use `binary_crossentropy` for the loss while having `sigmoid` for activation in the final layer (output layer). However, with this I am getting a resulting `accuracy` and `val_accuracy` of `~0.0931` and `~0.0937` respectively.

For the multi-label classification, is using the accuracy metric the best fit? I've looked around and some suggest that other metrics such as `binary_accuracy` may be better..

So the question is, how can one best evaluate the multi-label classification?

**EDIT:** For reference, I have 26 label columns in my target "classes" and the dataset consist of 21 columns. The entire dataset the model is trained on has ~82k samples.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739820/keras-merging-class-prediction-with-labels) post it is correct to use binary_crossentropy. Adding a softmax layer as a last layer is a first change one could do to your model as noted in the answer below in that thread. Furthermore regarding your actual question: As mentioned in the linked post you might want to go for precision/recall instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However w/r to the softmax suggestion the final score for each class should be independent of each other. Thus we can not apply softmax activation, because softmax converts the score into probabilities taking other scores into consideration and thats why sigmoid i think is the preferred.

As for the answer in that post, what would make up the pred_test_input for model predictions? Could this simply be a random sample of the dataset used to fit the model?

Comment: @rshah model.predict(pred_test_input): That means you apply your model to evaluate the performance on not-before-known samples. So you should actually NOT take samples of the dataset you already used for training. Usually you split into training, validation and then also test.