# Metrics and Loss function keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Code -

```
def define_model():
    # channel 1

    inputs1 = Input(shape=(32,1))
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=2, activation='relu')(inputs1)
    #bat1 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv1)
    flat1 = Flatten()(pool1)

    # channel 2

    inputs2 = Input(shape=(32,1))
    conv2 = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(inputs2)

    pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv2)

    flat2 = Flatten()(pool2)

    # channel 3

    inputs3 = Input(shape=(32,1))
    conv3 = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(inputs3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv3)
    flat3 = Flatten()(pool3)

    # channel 4

    inputs4 = Input(shape=(32,1))
    conv4 = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=6, activation='relu')(inputs4)

    pool4 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv4)

    flat4 = Flatten()(pool4)

    # merge

    merged = concatenate([flat1, flat2, flat3, flat4])

    # interpretation
    dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(merged)
    dense2 = Dense(96, activation='relu')(dense1)

    outputs = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(dense2)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2, inputs3, inputs4 ], outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='/content/q.png')

    return model

model_concat = define_model()

# fit model
print()
red_lr= ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',patience=2,verbose=2,factor=0.001,min_delta=0.01)
check=ModelCheckpoint(filepath=r'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/gen/concatcnn.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only = True)


History = model_concat.fit([X_train, X_train, X_train, X_train], y_train , epochs=20, verbose = 1 ,validation_data=([X_test, X_test, X_test, X_test], y_test), callbacks = [check, red_lr], batch_size = 32)

model_concat.summary
```

Unfortunately, I used binary crossentropy as loss and 'accuracy' as metrics. I got above 90% of val_accuracy.

Then, I found this link, [Keras binary_crossentropy vs categorical_crossentropy performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/keras-binary-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-performance).

After reading the first answer, I used binary crossentropy as loss and categorical crossentropy as metrics...

Even though, I Changed this, the val_acc is not improving, it shows around 62%.  what to do...

I minimised the model complexity to learn the data, but the accuracy is not improving. Am I miss anything...

Data set shape, x_train is (800,32) y_train is (200,32) y_train is (800,10) and y_test is (200, 10). Before fed into Network, I used standard scalar in x.and changed the x_train and, x_test shape to (800, 32, 1) and, (200, 32, 1).

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use `BCE` then output activation function  should be `sigmoid` instead of `softmax`

Comment: @Vishak Raj: Can you please let us know if your problem is resolved by changing the Activation Function from `softmax` to `sigmoid`. If it is not resolved, if your Data is Image Data, dividing the Value of Pixels by 255, instead of using Standard Scaler should help. Thanks!