# Poor accuracy of CNN model with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I need advice. I got a very poor result(10% accuracy) when building a CNN model with Keras when only using a subset of CIFAR10 dataset (only use 10000 data, 1000 per class). How can I increase the accuracy? I try to change/increase the epoch, but the result is still the same. Here is my CNN architecture :

```
cnn = models.Sequential()
cnn.add(layers.Conv2D(25, (3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
cnn.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(layers.Conv2D(50, (3, 3)))
cnn.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(layers.Conv2D(100, (3, 3)))
cnn.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(layers.Dense(100))
cnn.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(layers.Dense(10))
cnn.add(layers.Activation('softmax'))
```

compile and fit:

```
EPOCHS = 200
BATCH_SIZE = 10
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

cnn.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE),
            loss='binary_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

history_cnn = cnn.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),callbacks=[es, mc],verbose=0)
```

The data i use is CIFAR10, but i only take 1000 images per class so total data is only 10000. I use normalization for preprocessing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the problem is the loss. Your dataset is a **multi-class problem**, not a binary and not multi-label one

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/why-binary-crossentropy-and-categorical-crossentropy-give-different-performances):

> The classes are completely mutually exclusive. There is no overlap
> between automobiles and trucks. "Automobile" includes sedans, SUVs,
> things of that sort. "Truck" includes only big trucks. Neither
> includes pickup trucks.

In this situation is suggested the use of the `categorical crossentropy`. Keep in mind that if your label are sparse (encoded with the number between 0 and 999) and not as one hot encoded vector ([0, 0, 0 ... 1, 0, 0]) you should use the `sparse categorical crossentropy`.

- not sparse (labels encoded as vectors [0, 0, 1,....0])

  ```
  cnn.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE),
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
  ```
- sparse (labels encoded as numbers in (0, ... 999))

  ```
  cnn.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE),
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
  ```

Also, the learning rate is quite high (0.1). I'll suggest you to start with something lower (0.001) for example.

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/why-binary-crossentropy-and-categorical-crossentropy-give-different-performances) is also relevant for your problem

Edit: my bad, for the number of filters it is a commong approach having an increasing number of filters

Comment: hi, thanks before, but after i tried (change the loss to 'categorical_crossentropy' and learning rate to 0.001), the loss is much lower than before, but the accuracy still 10%

Comment: @thenoirlatte did you try sparse_categorical_crossentropy? Maybe you have sparse labels

Comment: probably you have sparse labels, with 1000 classes it's quite heavy to keep the labels in that way in memory

Comment: my bad...I forgot to run it from the beginning, the accuracy  is higher now (50%), I'll try to change to sparse_categorical_crossentropy and see the result