# Calculating categorical accuracy manually doesn't match the one given by keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm having trouble in interpreting the output of Keras `model.fit()` method.

**The setting**

```
print(tf.version.VERSION) # 2.3.0
print(keras.__version__) # 2.4.0
```

I have a simple feedforward model for a 3-class classification problem:

```py
def get_baseline_mlp(signal_length):
    input_tensor = keras.layers.Input(signal_length, name="input")
    dense_1 = keras.layers.Flatten()(input_tensor)

    dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(name='dense_1',activation='relu',units=500)(dense_1)
    dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(name='dense_2',activation='relu',units=500)(dense_1)
    dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(name='dense_3',activation='relu',units=500)(dense_1)
    dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(name='dense_4',activation='softmax',units=3, bias_initializer='zero')(dense_1)

    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=[dense_1])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

My training data are univariate timeseries, and my output is a one-hot encoded vector of length 3 (I have 3 classes in my classification problem)

Model is compiled as following:

```
mlp_base.compile(optimizer=optimizer, 
                           loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                           metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

I have a function to manually calculate accuracy of my prediction with two methods:

```py
def get_accuracy(model, true_x, true_y): 
    res = model.predict(true_x)
    res = np.rint(res)
    right = 0
    for i in range(len(true_y[:, 0])):
        if np.array_equal(res[i, :], true_y[i, :]):
            #print(res[i,:], tr_y[i,:])
            right += 1
        else:
            pass
    tot = len(true_y[:,0])
    print('True - total', right, tot)
    print('acc: {}'.format((right/tot)))
    print()
    print(' method 2 - categorical')
    res = model.predict(true_x)
    res = np.argmax(res, axis=-1)
    true_y = np.argmax(true_y, axis=-1)
    right = 0
    for i in range(len(true_y)):
        if res[i] == true_y[i]:
            right += 1
        else:
            pass
    tot = len(true_y)
    print('True - total', right, tot)
    print('acc: {}'.format((right/tot)))
```

**The Problem**

At training end, the outputted categorical accuracy does not match the one I get using my custom function.

Training output:

```
Model: "functional_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           [(None, 9000)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_8 (Flatten)          (None, 9000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 500)               4500500   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 500)               250500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 500)               250500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 1503      
=================================================================
Total params: 5,003,003
Trainable params: 5,003,003
Non-trainable params: 0
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Fit model on training data
Epoch 1/2
20/20 [==] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.3796 categorical_accuracy: 0.3250 - val_loss: 0.9240 - 
Epoch 2/2
20/20 [==] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.8131 categorical_accuracy: 0.6100 - val_loss: 1.2811
```

Output of accuracy function:

```
True / total 169 200
acc: 0.845

 method 2
True / total 182 200
acc: 0.91
```

Why am I getting wrong results? Is my accuracy implementation wrong?

## Update

Correcting the settings as desertnaut suggested is still not working.

Output of fit:

```py
Epoch 1/3
105/105 [===] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 1.7666 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2980
Epoch 2/3
105/105 [===] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 1.2380 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4432
Epoch 3/3
105/105 [===] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 1.0318 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5989
```

If I use the categorical accuracy function by keras I'm still getting different results.

```py
cat_acc =  keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
cat_acc.update_state(tr_y2, y_pred)
print(cat_acc.result().numpy()) # outputs : 0.7211079
```

Interestingly, if I compute with the above methods the validation accuracy I get consistent output.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure about your accuracy calculation (seems unnecessary convoluted, and we always prefer vector calculations over `for` loops), but there are two issues with your code that may impact the results (or even render them meaningless).

The first issue is that, since your are in a multiclass setting, you should compile your model with `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`, and **not** `'binary_crossentropy'`; check own answer in [Why binary_crossentropy and categorical_crossentropy give different performances for the same problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/why-binary-crossentropy-and-categorical-crossentropy-give-different-performances) to see what may happen when you mix losses & accuracies that way (plus, a `'binary_accuracy'` here is absolutely meaningless).

The second issue is that you erroneously use `activation='sigmoid'` for your last layer: since you are in a multi-class (not multi-label) setting with your labels one-hot encoded, the activation in your last layer should be `softmax`, and not `sigmoid`.

Comment: Thanks, the wrong setup was the cause of the mismatch between the computed accuracy in my function (method 2) and the one from keras.
With the same setup but with binary_crossentropy, sigmoid as last layer activation and binary accuracy there is a mismatch.
What is wrong with the (convoluted) first part of the accuracy function? Is that the correct way of computing accuracy for the binary classification setting?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @MickHardins As already said, we don't use `for` loops in such cases - we use vector & array  operations instead; you should be able to calculate the accuracy in ~ 5 lines using only array methods like `argmax`, `mean` etc. See the respective [scikit-learn function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L186) for some inspiration. And if the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it.

Comment: I've updated the question as it seems that the problem is unsolved.