# Keras: model.evaluate vs model.predict accuracy difference in multi-class NLP task

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am training a simple model in keras for NLP task with following code. Variable names are self explanatory for train, test and validation set. This dataset has 19 classes so final layer of the network has 19 outputs. Labels are also one-hot encoded.

```python
nb_classes = 19
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(nb_words,
                     EMBEDDING_DIM,
                     weights=[embedding_matrix],
                     input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                     trainable=False))
model1.add(LSTM(num_lstm, dropout=rate_drop_lstm, recurrent_dropout=rate_drop_lstm))
model1.add(Dropout(rate_drop_dense))
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.add(Dense(num_dense, activation=act))
model1.add(Dropout(rate_drop_dense))
model1.add(BatchNormalization())

model1.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation = 'sigmoid'))


model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#One hot encode all labels
ytrain_enc = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
yval_enc = np_utils.to_categorical(val_labels)
ytestenc = np_utils.to_categorical(test_labels)

model1.fit(train_data, ytrain_enc,
             validation_data=(val_data, yval_enc),
             epochs=200,
             batch_size=384,
             shuffle=True,
             verbose=1)
```

After first epoch, this gives me these outputs.

```python
Epoch 1/200
216632/216632 [==============================] - 2442s - loss: 0.1427 - acc: 0.9443 - val_loss: 0.0526 - val_acc: 0.9826
```

Then I evaluate my model on testing dataset and this also shows me accuracy around 0.98.

```python
model1.evaluate(test_data, y = ytestenc, batch_size=384, verbose=1)
```

However, the labels are one-hot encoded, so I need prediction vector of classes so that I can generate confusion matrix etc. So I use,

```python
PREDICTED_CLASSES = model1.predict_classes(test_data, batch_size=384, verbose=1)
temp = sum(test_labels == PREDICTED_CLASSES)
temp/len(test_labels)
0.83
```

This shows that total predicted classes were 83% accurate however `model1.evaluate` shows 98% accuracy!! What am I doing wrong here? Is my loss function okay with categorical class labels? Is my choice of `sigmoid` activation function for prediction layer okay? or there is difference in the way keras evaluates a model? Please suggest on what can be wrong. This is my first try to make a deep model so I don't have much understanding of what's wrong here.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I have found the problem. `metrics=['accuracy']` calculates accuracy automatically from cost function. So using `binary_crossentropy` shows binary accuracy, not categorical accuracy. Using `categorical_crossentropy` automatically switches to categorical accuracy and now it is the same as calculated manually using `model1.predict()`. Yu-Yang was right to point out the cost function and activation function for multi-class problem.

P.S: One can get both categorical and binary accuracy by using `metrics=['binary_accuracy', 'categorical_accuracy']`

Comment: Great catch (+1) - unfortunately, I had to re-discover & understand this issue from scratch - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327601/why-is-binary-crossentropy-more-accurate-than-categorical-crossentropy-for-multi/46004661#46004661 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/keras-binary-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-performance/46038271#46038271 - nevertheless, I updated my answers to link to yours...

Comment: @desertnaut thnx a lot for sharing these precious resources, I had a doubt while using binary_crossentropy just like for accuracy we had to use 'binary_accuracy', similar to this do we have to use some other recall metric ? Because model.evaluate() recall value is slightly varying from model.predict() method's recall.