# Keras model evaluate() vs. predict_classes() gives different accuracy results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have been using TF2.0 recently. I have trained a simple CNN model (with Keras Sequential API) for binary classification of images. I have used tf.data.Dataset for loading the images from disk. Actually the model got pretty good accuracy, with train binary_accuracy: 0.9831 and validation binary_accuracy: 0.9494.

Tried evaluating the model using model.evaluate(). It gave binary accuracy of 0.9460. But when I tried to calculate binary accuracy manually using predict_classes(), I get around 0.384. I dont know what was the issue. Please help me out.

I have added my code used for compiling and training the model. Also the code for evaluating my model.

```py
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(train_x),tf.constant(train_y)))
val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(val_x),tf.constant(val_y)))

train_data = train_data.map(preproc).shuffle(buffer_size=100).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_data = val_data.map(preproc).shuffle(buffer_size=100).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

time1 = time.time()
history = model.fit(train_data.repeat(),
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                    validation_data=val_data.repeat(),
                    validation_steps=VAL_STEPS,
                    callbacks=[checkpointer])

29/29 [==============================] - 116s 4s/step - loss: 0.0634 - binary_accuracy: 0.9826 - val_loss: 0.1559 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9494
```

Now testing with unseen data

```py
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(unseen_faces),tf.constant(unseen_labels)))
test_data = test_data.map(preproc).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model.evaluate(test_data)

9/9 [==============================] - 19s 2s/step - loss: 0.1689 - binary_accuracy: 0.9460
```

The same model, when I tried to calculate accuracy using model.predict_classes with same dataset, the prediction results are far from the evaluation report. The binary accuracy comes around 38%.

**Edit 1:**
Pre-processing function I used while training

```py
def preproc(file_path,label):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
    img = (tf.cast(img, tf.float32)/127.5) - 1
    return tf.image.resize(img,(IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_WIDTH)),label
```

**Manual prediction code**

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

#Testing preprocessing function
def preproc_test(file_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
    img = (tf.cast(img, tf.float32)/127.5) - 1
    return tf.image.resize(img,(IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_WIDTH))

unseen_faces = []
unseen_labels = []
for im_path in glob.glob('dataset/data/*'):
    unseen_faces.append(im_path)
    if 'real' in i:
        unseen_labels.append(0)
    else:
        unseen_labels.append(1)

unseen_faces = list(map(preproc_test,unseen_faces))
unseen_faces = tf.stack(unseen_faces)

predicted_labels = model.predict_classes(unseen_faces)

print(classification_report(unseen_labels,predicted_labels,[0,1]))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.54      0.41      0.47        34
           1       0.41      0.54      0.47        26

    accuracy                           0.47        60
   macro avg       0.48      0.48      0.47        60
weighted avg       0.48      0.47      0.47        60
```

Comment: Please show how exactly you are calculating the accuracy with `predict_classes`. And what is `preproc`?

Comment: @desertnaut The preproc is a preprocessing function. Please refer Edit 1 for code

Comment: Found an answer. Use Categorical_Crossentry loss. See the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799474/keras-model-evaluate-vs-model-predict-accuracy-difference-in-multi-class-nlp-ta#)

Answer (score 1):

Your model is doing good both during `training` and `testing`. Evaluation accuracy comes on the basis of prediction so maybe you are making some logical mistake while using `model.predict_classes()`. Please check if you are using the trained model weights and not any randomly initialized model while evaluating it.

`evaluate`: The model will set apart this fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. `model.evaluate()` is for evaluating your trained model. Its output is accuracy or loss, not prediction to your input data.

`predict`: Generates output predictions for the input samples. `model.predict()` actually predicts, and its output is target value, predicted from your input data.

P.S.: For binary classification problem accuracy <=50% is worse than a random guess.

Comment: Hi, Please check the code I added in Edit 1. Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: I can't see any problem in your code. Please see if you are using the same image format(BGR/ RGB) and preprocessing in training and inference. Also, check if you are using trained weights during prediction.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it is because the shape of my ground truth and predicted results are different. I was loading data by `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()`, where the `y_train` is a 2d ndarray of shape `(50000,1)` yet the prediction from `model.predict_classes` is of shape `(50000,)`. If I directly compare them by `np.mean(pred==y_train)` I would have a result of `0.1` which is not correct. Instead `np.mean(pred==np.squeeze(y_train))` gives the correct result.